# Download PDF from Meteor(react) iOS mobile App to Device

Tags: ios, reactjs, cordova, meteor

I have a weird problem with my Meteor(react) iOS mobile App. The problem is that I have to download PDF document in my app through button provided by react-html-table-to-excel npm package and when I click the button, it shows me the PDF document with no back link.

My piece of code,

```
import ReactHTMLTableToExcel from 'react-html-table-to-excel';

// this is the button to download pdf using id of table
<ReactHTMLTableToExcel className="fa fa-download btn" 
table="listOfUsersDwnld" filename="listOfUsersDwnld" sheet="tablexls"/>

<table id="listOfUsersDwnld" className="table">
</table>
```

Hence, when I open the PDF document in my app through a button, it takes me to a dead end and there is no way I can go back to the main page of my app.
Also added npm cordova "cordova-plugin-file" package. But still no breakthrough.

It is working in browser but not in ios-application. Earlier it was not even opening pdf but then I added allow navigation rule and since then it is opening but unable to download.

My question is that how can allow downloadable pdf file in iOS? Any internal element for the iOS may be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use InAppBrowser plugin with _blank option to open the file

Comment: But I am expecting pdf to download and not to open.

Comment: You download it locally and then open in InAppBrowser. After downloading, use the local url of the file to open InAppBrowser

Comment: Exactly that is what is I also expecting but situation here is I am unable to download it at first place but instead file view is displaying and no download is happening. May be something to do with permissions, no idea.